# Removing rails from server rack

Tags: rack

Not sure this is the place for this but I'm banging my head against a wall and figure before I lose a finger trying to remove these rails I'd give it a shot.

Anyone have any idea how to get these rails out of a server rack?  It's more like a shelf instead of pull out rails, I cannot get them to budge.[image]

[image]

New pic

[image]

Comment: first pic, upper mount, there is some sort of a locking mechanism that allows you to retract that big thick square pin

Comment: @Dan Yup, there's a retractable "nubbin" on either the front or the back of the rails that allows you to disengage the supports and then retract the rail away from the rack mount.

Comment: Yep. It's the silver button in the top hole. Push it in to release.

Comment: What I circled?  (see new pic above)

Comment: Push that lever, lift up on the rail, and then retract.

Comment: Yup, that did it.  One rail is stuck and I did manage to slice my finger open trying but almost there...thanks!